# faster Sieve of Erathostenes and prime number factorization in Java

Tags: java, primes, factorization, sieve

My input is an `Integer`. Up to that value, all prime numbers should be found and printed in 5 columns, then I have to "prime factorize" the integer and print the result.

It wokrs fine, but it'ts too slow...

```
public class Bsp07 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

     System.out.println("Enter the upper bound for prime number search");
     int n = SavitchIn.readLineInt();
     int[] aZahlen = new int[n - 1];
     for (int el = 0, zahl = 2; el != n - 1; el++, zahl++)
        aZahlen[el] = zahl;

     int p = 2, altesP; // next unmarked number
     boolean aus = false; // when unmarked elements are "aus" (off)

     while (aus == false) {

     // marks Elements; using For loop since for-each loop doesn't work
        for (int i = 0; i < aZahlen.length; i++) {
           if ((aZahlen[i] % p == 0) && (aZahlen[i] != p))
              aZahlen[i] = 0;
        }

        altesP = p; // merkt sich altes p
     // update p, find next unmarked Element
        for (int el : aZahlen) {
           if ((el != 0) && (el > altesP)) {
              p = el;
              break;
           }
        }
     // if p stayed the same unmarked elements are "aus" (off)
        if (altesP == p)
           aus = true;
     }

     int nervVar = 0;
     for (int pr : aZahlen) {
        if(pr==0) 
           continue;
        System.out.print(pr + " ");
        nervVar++;
        if ((nervVar % 5 == 0)) System.out.print("\n");
     }

     /* Factorization */
     System.out.print("\n" + n + " = ");
     for (int i = 0, f = 0; n != 1; i++, f++) {
        while(aZahlen[i]==0) i++;
     /*
      * If the prime divides: divide by it, print the prime,
      * Counter for further continuous decrease with prime number if n = 1,
      * Stop
      */
        if (n % aZahlen[i] == 0) {
           n /= aZahlen[i];
        // So that the first time is not *
           if (f != 0)
              System.out.print(" * " + aZahlen[i]);
           else
              System.out.print(aZahlen[i]);
           i--;
        }
        // So that f remains zero if no division by 2
        else
           f--;
     }
     System.out.println();
  }
```

}

Where can I save some resources? btw I can only use arrays for now... Sorry for the german comments. Just if some really unnecessary long loop or something similar catches your eye

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than apologizing for the German comments, why don't you translate them?

Comment: http://translate.google.com  <--- PS - you should never code or comment in a language other than English.  It's the Universal standard.

Comment: @TheSmose Clearly, OP speaks English.

Comment: Why are you using an into array. Wouldn't bitset be better?

Comment: Geez, first post, having first comment by JonSkeet, edit by Marko Topolnik :) lucky guy

Comment: @TheSmose: although I agree with you, if you've ever worked with developers from other countries (the French for example) you know that this is not really possible ;)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Did my comment imply otherwise?

Comment: @WoLpH I've worked extensively with developers from all over the world, and I know that in a controlled enviroment, it's entirely possible for everyone to code/comment in English, and an enforced standard in many larger companies. The suggestion wasn't for my benefit. It was for those who may struggle with English, but are interested in expanding their opportunities as developers.

Comment: @TheSmose Why would a person speaking both German and English need the services of *Google translate*? Yes, your comment implies otherwise.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I see what you mean.  I suggested Google Translate for ease, not for necessity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of searching up to `n-1`, I would only search up to `(int) sqrt(n)`.
Figure out why this is sufficient yourself. ;-)

I do not get why you need `altesP` at all. Can't you just increment `p` by two?

I wouldn't filter by striking out. I would build a positive list, and add the prime numbers you have found.

Look into fast primeness tests that can rule out a number without having to go through the whole sieve.

So do the following changes to your code, please:

1. instead of erasing `aZahlen`, build a list of `primes`. `sqrtN = (int)sqrt(n)` as allocation size should be fine, and use a count `foundPrimes` for how many primes you know.
2. Iterate over `p` up to `<= sqrtN` without any fuzz. See if any of the known primes is a divisor, otherwise you found a new prime. Output it, and store it in your `foundPrimes` list.

Answer (score -1):

An `int[]` uses 32-bit per value. If you use `byte[]` this will use 8-bits per value and if you use BitSet, it will use 1-bit per value (32x smaller)

Comment: He is not running out of memory. `int[]` might be faster than `byte[]` (plus he probably needs to test primes larger than `127`!) and certainly faster than `BitSet`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you want to do. I think you are trying to factor an integer by trial division by primes. For that, you don't need all the primes less than the integer, only the primes less than the square root of the integer, so all you need is a simple Sieve of Eratosthenes to select the primes:

```
function sieve(n)
  bits := makeArray(2..n, True)
  ps := []
  for p from 2 to n
    if bits[p]
      ps.append(p)
      for i from p+p to n step p
        bits[i] = False
  return ps
```

Then you can use those primes to perform the factorization:

```
function factors(n)
  ps := primes(sqrt(n))
  fs := []
  p := head(ps)
  while p*p <= n
    if n%p == 0
      fs.append(p)
      n := n / p
    else
      ps := tail(ps)
      p := head(ps)
  fs.append(n)
  return fs
```

I discuss programming with prime numbers in an [essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog, which includes implementations of both these algorithms in Java. The essay also includes other more efficient methods of enumerating primes and factoring integers that those given above.

Comment: calling `factors` with a prime argument will cause `head` to be called with an empty list, yes? Depending on language in use, this may cause a run-time error (like, calling `(factors 29)` in Scheme).

Comment: If you try to factor a prime number, you deserve whatever happens to you.